# What does this quantum mechanics diagram about adaptive mutations mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, biology, decoherence

I'm a current high school student and I’m aspiring to become a biochemist. I’m at the moment writing an article about adaptive mutations but there is a lot of tricky quantum mechanics in it which I simply don't get. I have asked everyone and got no answer until someone recommended to ask it in a forum. I would more than grateful if someone could actually explain to me what on earth is going on in the diagram I have shown below. Here is also a link to the article if you want extra context or just give it a read because it is very interesting:https://www.academia.edu/13243691/A_quantum_mechanical_model_of_adaptive_mutation
[image]

Comment: The diagram tries to show how the wave function changes depending on various events. Which, to be honest, I think looks very speculative even if the quantum stuff is correct. Normally quantum mechanics is not used when talking about adaptive mutations! This paper is not exactly mainstream stuff, although it is part of the scientific discussion. Do you really think it is relevant to your article?

Comment: The question is not very clear. What exactly is your doubt?

Comment: Thanks, Andres Sandberg it isn't essential to the article but I just found it very interesting, also I thought it would be useful to explain the difference between adaptive and random mutations.

Comment: My question Yashas is essentially what does this diagram actually suggest or mean when talking about adaptive mutations

Answer (score 1):

At first, it needs to be mentioned that quantum mechanical rules are applicable to DNA molecule, which is a bunch of hydrogen bonds between various bases. Quantum biologists have proposed that main force which drives DNA random mutations is proton tunneling between hydrogen bonds. This article just adds another layer of "selective mutations", where idea is raised that DNA molecule couplings with surrounding cell environment (chemical ingredients, diluent in it, etc) can force the rate of proton tunneling be higher, thus inducing selective mutations in a cell.

Btw, this article is published in a very credible scientific **Elsevier** journal (BioSystems branch). I don't have much experience with this particular bio-physics branch, but in my Physics master studies,- I've read bunch of useful Physics articles in Elsevier journal related to optics, quantum mechanics, laser physics and such. So this article reasearch must be ok in my view.

Comment: Thank you very much